# How do I get the Shortcuts app in iOS 12?

Tags: automation, ios, shortcuts-app

I recently upgraded my iPhone 5s and iPad mini 4 to iOS 12. I came across Shortcuts app for iOS 12 in [this review article](https://www.theverge.com/2018/9/17/17847104/apple-siri-shortcuts-ios-12-app-download-features).

I think Shortcuts app is pretty interesting and would like to give it a try. However, I was not able to find the app on my iPhone and iPad. I thought it will come installed as part of iOS 12 like Stocks and Tips apps.

In the App Store app, I can see all the other apps published by Apple, but Shortcuts app was not in the list. Even searching for **Shortcuts** on the App Store doesn't show the app.

How can I get the app? Is it available for my iPhone and iPad, or are they too old to run the app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcuts app is available for all the devices running iOS 12. You can use this [App Store link](https://itunes.apple.com/app/workflow/id915249334) to access the app.

Open this answer directly on your iPhone/iPad and tap on the link above to directly open the App Store page of the Shortcuts app and download it. Alternatively, open the link in Safari for macOS and AirDrop it to your iPhone/iPad. This will directly open the App Store page for the app where can download it.

Your devices aren't too old to run the app. There is no special device capabilities required for running the app. The app is supported on all the devices capable of running iOS 12. (For iPhones that goes as far back as iPhone 5s.)

Shortcuts used to be a 3rd party app called [Workflow](https://workflow.is) before Apple acquired the app and hired the development team. You can learn more about the app [here](https://workflow.is/docs).

Apple has shared a pretty in-depth user guide explaining how to use this big step forward for iOS - the features are baked deeply into iOS and 3rd party developers can write extensions that let shortcuts and Siri reach into those apps and do work and automation.

- [Shortcuts User Guide](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks I was able to get the app that way. Really nifty way to get the app on iOS device. I think Shortcuts app should come bundled as a part of iOS 12. Thanks again.

Comment: @Madhu I’ve explained how this was a third party app that Apple bought out the entire company - offered jobs to the developer and most importantly - gave a like to Federico Viticci’s web site where he and some amazing people write how to use this app.